# Error 3021 when I run VBA request to a linked table in Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

I want to send a request (query) from Excel to an Access database. But when my request targets a linked table it triggers the 3021 error. However when I run the same resquest in Access, itself, the request editor (dynaset) shows 1300 rows.

I have tested various solutions:

1. I tried executing the resquest with

   conObj.execute(SQLString)
2. Then with the following, with the same error

   RecordSet.Open SQL, "DsnODBC"
3. Finally with

   RecSet.Open SQL, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

But nothing works; every time I get an error at this line

```
LesResult = RecSet.GetRows()
```

```vb
'=========Instansiation des objets=========' 'init object
Set RecSet = New ADODB.recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
'=========================================='

'===========Connection à la base===========' 'DB connect
conn.ConnectionString = ThisWorkbook.leControler.strConnectString
conn.Open ThisWorkbook.leControler.strConnectString
'=========================================='


Select Case HerbierAdmin.ActiveAction

    Case "PM":
        [Somme code]

        SQL = "SELECT SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] "
        SQL = SQL & "FROM SAP_ClassItems "
        SQL = SQL & "WHERE ((SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] Like 'PM 21S *'));"
        Debug.Print SQL
        Set RecSet = conn.Execute("SELECT SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] FROM SAP_ClassItems WHERE ((SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] Like 'PM 21S *'));")

        LesResult = RecSet.GetRows() 'error here
        RecSet.Close

        For i = 0 To UBound(LesResult, 2)
           Me.ListeBox.AddItem (LesResult(0, i)) 'add result to drop down box
        Next
```

Expected result: The query result can be added to a drop-down list.

Comment: what have you defined lesresult as ?

Comment: I defined it as variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to Harassed Dad. The solution is place '%' instead of '*' on the like instruction.

Answer (score 0):

skip the variable:

```
Set RecSet = conn.Execute("SELECT SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] FROM SAP_ClassItems WHERE ((SAP_ClassItems.[Plan de montage] Like 'PM 21S *'));")

    Do until recsec.eof
       Me.ListeBox.AddItem recsec(0) 'add result to drop down box
       recsec.movenext
    loop 
    recsec.close
```

Comment: I don't not why, but when I send this requests In Excel EOF is directly equal true. However, when I run the same resquest in Access, itself, the request editor shows 1300 rows.
So when I use your code. I have no entry add in my drop down box

Comment: Ahh! There's a neat gotcha here - the Access ODBC driver doesn't support * as a wildcard it needs %  instead - change the sql appropriately. Sorry didn't remember that